# After some long exploration, how do I find a system with populated stations to dock?

Tags: elite-dangerous

One week ago, I have decided to go for a trip to find black holes after getting a fuel scoop. Right now, I am very very far away from the starting systems (may be >5000 to 10000 light years).

I want to find a station to dock, buy some new equipment and stuff. However, I have been searching for days and I still cannot find any. All systems around me only contain one to two big planets, nothing else. I am starting to feel frustrated.

Other than detonating myself in the cold space and start again, is there anything I can do to find a station other than randomly fly to systems and check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the populated space is near Sol. You can direct your ship towards Sol by moving towards the 0,0,0 coordinates on the Galaxy Map.
Otherwise you might be able to find nearby populated systems on the Galaxy map by zooming out and playing with the View filters - anything with an Economy likely has a station.

Comment: I guess that essentially means that if I go 10000 LYs away to explore, I must then again travel 10000 LYs way back to sell my data or buy something?

Comment: I can't say 100% if that is truly the case, but from what I've seen so far I only the few hundred light years around Sol has any human population. I would love for someone to correct me on this since it would give an interesting destination to reach.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Yes. So far as anybody knows, there are no stations more than a few hundred Ly from Sol.

Comment: UPDATE: as part of the ongoing story, there have been colonizing efforts far away from Sol. However, AFAIK, this is limited to one area. As I'm not playing anymore, don't know the exact details.

Answer (score 3):

Third party tools work great for this sort of thing. Head to [inara.cz/galaxy-nearest](https://inara.cz/galaxy-nearest), input your current location, and select "Universal cartographics". This will show you the closest station that buys exploration data.