# Will I discover space stations through exploring?

Tags: elite-dangerous

With my new ASP I start exploring the milky way. I discover stars and planets. Can/will I also discover space stations or are all space stations already publicly known?

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205459/after-some-long-exploration-how-do-i-find-a-system-with-populated-stations-to-d

Comment: That question is related, but does not answer my question specifically. Interesting read, though.

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean to imply that your question was a duplicate (it's not), just that it covers similar content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now all space stations are publicly known. The only thing you can discover are planets.